# xsd to c# without included xsd

Tags: c#, xsd

To generate classes from xsd file is it necessary need included/imported xsd? Is possible to generate it without included/imported xsd? Because I want write own xsd to C# classes generator.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns="" xmlns:Extended="" xmlns:xsd="" targetNamespace="">
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="file2.xsd"/>
    <xsd:import namespace="" schemaLocation="file2.xsd"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="ActualEndTimeType">
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:restriction base="DateTimeType"/>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="ActualFinishTimeType">
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:restriction base="DateTimeType"/>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="ActualStartTimeType">
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:restriction base="DateTimeType"/>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <-- etc... -->
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: How is it supposed to work when it doesnt know what a certain type is since it is defined in another xsd?

Comment: I thought same like you but i wanted be sure. Thanks for reply.